# Changing default DPI when opening PDF with QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, pdf

Every time a PDF is opened using QGIS the resolution is quite poor. I believe this is because the standard gdal pdf driver behind QGIS uses a default value of 150 dpi. (see here https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/pdf.html)

But, when using gdal (e.g. gdal_translate) from the cmd window I am able to configure the desired dpi using the option -co GDAL_PDF_DPI 600.

Is it possible to change this option in QGIS?

Using Settings - Data source- GDAL - PDF only the create options can be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set `GDAL_PDF_DPI` as an environment variable.

Go to `Settings / Options / System` and add this environment variable with the desired value of 600 under `Environment`. Restart QGIS and see if it now works.
This should also add it to the environment, so when you open the command window and run `gdal_translate` you should not need to add it to the command line.

For other variables you can set in this fashion for GDAL, see https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html

Comment: Nice! This worked just fine for me importing a pdf to the main canvas and the layout manger using QGIS 3.22.1.